# Until when was Har Sinai on fire?

Tags: har-sinai, ekev

We learn in [Parshat Eikev](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.9.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he):

> וָאֵ֗פֶן וָֽאֵרֵד֙ מִן־הָהָ֔ר וְהָהָ֖ר בֹּעֵ֣ר בָּאֵ֑שׁ וּשְׁנֵי֙ לֻחֹ֣ת הַבְּרִ֔ית עַ֖ל שְׁתֵּ֥י יָדָֽי׃
>
> I turned and went down the mountain, a mountain ablaze with fire, the two Tablets of the Covenant on my two hands.

**When did this fire (which is mentioned at Matan Torah already) cease to exist?**

The closest I could find is what the [HaEmek Davar says in this verse](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.9.15?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Haamek_Davar_on_Deuteronomy.9.15.2&lang2=he) - that since the fire was still burning, Moshe understood that this was a message that he'd have to go up again to get another set of Luchos, hence the *permission* to break the first set.

> וההר בוער באש. ועדיין היה בוער באש ולא היה כמו שאמר ה׳ מתחלה במשוך היובל המה יעלו. ממילא יהא נפסק האש וגלוי שכינה. אבל כאשר ירדתי לאחור ראיתי שעדיין ההר בוער באש. ומזה היה לי הוכחה דרצונו ית׳ ליתן לי לוחות שניות ומסתמא רצונו שישברו לוחות אלו. ויהיה נצרך לוחות שניות:‏

This makes it sound like the fire burnt until Moshe come down on Yom Kippur with the 2nd Luchos, but it stopped before he actually came down (otherwise he would have had reason to break the 2nd set.)

But I cannot find anything explicit.

Comment: Also in Vaetchanan וַתִּקְרְבוּן וַתַּעַמְדוּן תַּחַת הָהָר וְהָהָר בֹּעֵר בָּאֵשׁ עַד לֵב הַשָּׁמַיִם

Answer (score 1):

Rashi in Tanis 21b writes - according to the version of the Rashash quoted on the side of many Gemaros, who himself is quoting earlier versions of Rashi - that the fire was there until the Mishkan was built on the  first of Nissan.  [The word in Rash should be כיום like the day, not ביום on the day.]

לא נסתלקה שכינה עד לוחות האחרונות שניתנו ביום הכפורים וגם כל ימות החורף שעסקו במלאכת המשכן שהתה שכינה בהר ומשם ניתנו כל המצות בקולי קולות ולפידים  - ביום / כיום -  קבלת עשרת הדברות עד אחד בניסן שהוקם המשכן ונסעה

Comment: Does that just say the Shechina remained on the mountain till 1 Nissan? Where do you see anything about the mountain burning?

Comment: @DoubleAA Does ולפידים mean fire?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but isn't that the voice of God not the mountain? וכל העם ראים את הקולות ואת הלפידים. That's different from ההר בער באש I'd think.